# How to derive the jump condition at $x=0$ for a fourth-order ordinary differential equation involving a derivative of the Dirac delta function?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, continuity, dirac-delta

Let's consider the fourth-order ordinary differential equation (ODE):
$$
f^{(4)}(x) - 2 f^{(2)}(x) + f(x) = \delta'(x) , \tag{1}
$$
where $f^{(n)}$ denotes the $n$th derivative with respect to $x$.

Given that the Dirac delta function is related to its derivative via $x\delta'(x) = -\delta(x)$, we can rewrite Eq. (1) as [[Wikipedia]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Derivatives_of_the_Dirac_delta_function):
$$
x \left[ f^{(4)}(x) - 2 f^{(2)}(x) + f(x) \right] = -\delta(x) . \tag{2}
$$

Our objective is to determine the jump condition at the interface $x=0$.

To obtain the jump condition, we start by integrating both sides of Eq. (2) by parts. This leads to the following expression:
$$
\left[ x \left( f^{(3)}-2f^{(1)}+f^{(-1)} \right) + f^{(2)}-2f+f^{(-2)} \right]_{x=-\epsilon}^\epsilon = 1\, ,
$$
where $\epsilon$ is a small positive value, approaching zero.

How can we rigorously obtain the jump condition at $x=0$?

It seems that the discontinuity in the second derivative might play a crucial role, but I'm struggling to establish a concrete connection. Any assistance or guidance on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Why do you think $\delta'(x)=\delta(x)/x$? I understand that $\delta'(x)=-\delta(x)\partial_x$.

Comment: @kevinkayaks This is what Wikipedia says: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Derivatives_of_the_Dirac_delta_function

Comment: No, you can't divide infinity by $x$ and get something meaningful. I believe you're rearranging a functional identity as if it were algebraic. Maybe double check that your identity holds using the definition of functional identity.

Comment: @kevinkayaks I don't see your point. What does $-\delta(x) \partial (\cdot)/\partial x$ actually mean?

Comment: It means $\int \delta'(x) f(x)dx = -\int \delta(x) f'(x) dx$. It is in contrast not true (as you claimed) that  $\int \delta'(x) f(x)dx = \int \delta(x)x^{-1}f(x) dx$, as you could show by counterexample. Functionals are equal if their integrals against a test function are equal. So I suggest to approach your problem with correct Dirac delta identities

Comment: It's true that $x\delta'=-\delta$ but the expression $\delta/x$ is not defined.

Comment: @md2perpe Thanks. I have adjusted the post accordingly. This however does not change the outlined calculations.

Comment: Can you consider other approaches?

Comment: @md2perpe Not sure if the problem can be approached differently.

Comment: I think that we can solve the differential equation. We can also reason about it using knowledge of when delta terms occur.

Comment: @md2perpe The general solution of the homogeneous equation is given by $(A+Bx)e^x + (C+Dx)e^{-x}$. The problem is how the jump conditions at the interface $x=0$ can be formulated.

Comment: 4th order equation in two domains gives 8 undetermined coefficients. Vanishing at either infinity reduces this to 6. Matching of $f$ itself gives 5. Is $f$ normalized ? Then you need 4. So the matching condition should involve a system of either 4 or 5 equations that you need to derive from the original ODE.

Comment: @kevinkayaks For $x<0$ we have $f(x) = (A+Bx)e^x$ and for $x>0$ we have $f(x) = (C+Dx)e^{-x}$. The unknown constants need to be determined from the boundary conditions imposed at $x=0$. It looks like $f$, $f'$, and $f^{(3)}$ are continuous but $f''$ is discontinuous, but I cannot prove that rigorously.

Comment: Can you explain why you think $f''$ is discontinuous? My tendency would be to assume all derivatives match up to some order

Comment: @kevinkayaks. Had the right hand side just been a plain delta term, then the function itself and its first and second derivatives had been continuous, but the third derivative not. Now the right hand side is the derivative of delta and then I agree with preuss that the second derivative is discontinuous.

Comment: You may use the Fourier transform in order to find a particular solution, since $\mathscr{F}[\delta'(x)](k) = ik$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transform the equation into a system of second order equations, using the freedom to chose the new component to combine the highest derivatives on both sides by setting $$f''=g(x)+\theta,$$ $\theta$ the unit jump function, thus $\theta'=\delta$. Then
$$
g''+\delta'-2(g+\theta)+f=\delta'
\\~\\
g''-2g+f=2\theta
$$
The linear system for $(f,g)$ now has piecewise constant right sides. Thus its solutions are $C^1$ and piecewise smooth.

In consequence, $f$ and $f'$ are continuous at $x=0$, $f''$ has a jump of size 1, $f'''=g'+\delta$ has no jump in the values left and right from $x=0$.

Answer (score 4):

For what its worth, OP's ODE can in fact be solved exactly via factorization:

$$\begin{align} \delta^{\prime}(x)
~\stackrel{(1)}{=}~&\left(\frac{d^2}{dx^2}-1\right)^2f(x)\cr
~=~&\left(\frac{d}{dx}+1\right)^2\left(\frac{d}{dx}-1\right)^2f(x)\cr 
~=~&e^{-x}\frac{d^2}{dx^2}e^{2x}\frac{d^2}{dx^2}e^{-x}f(x), 
\end{align}$$
or
$$\begin{align}
\frac{d^2}{dx^2}e^{2x}\frac{d^2}{dx^2}e^{-x}f(x)
~=~&e^x\delta^{\prime}(x)\cr
~=~&\delta^{\prime}(x)+(e^x-1)\delta^{\prime}(x)\cr 
~=~&\delta^{\prime}(x)-e^x\delta(x)\cr
~=~&\delta^{\prime}(x)-\delta(x). 
\end{align}$$
Integrating twice yields
$$
\frac{d^2}{dx^2}e^{-x}f(x)
~=~e^{-2x}\left(\frac{{\rm sgn}(x)-|x|}{2}+ax+b\right). 
$$
Integrating a third time yields
$$
\frac{d}{dx}e^{-x}f(x)
~=~e^{-2x}\left(\frac{2|x|-{\rm sgn}(x)}{8}+Ax+B\right)+\frac{{\rm sgn}(x)}{8}+C.
$$
Integrating a fourth time yields the complete solution
$$
f(x)
~=~e^{-x}\left(-\frac{|x|}{8}+\alpha x+\beta\right)+e^x\left(\frac{|x|}{8}+\gamma x+\delta\right). 
$$
A particular solution is
$$f(x)~=~\frac{|x|}{4}\sinh x. $$
It is easy to check that $f^{\prime\prime}$ has a jump of size 1 at $x=0$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $\partial$ denote the ordinary derivative where it is defined and let us use $'$ for the distributional derivative.

Assume that $f$ is smooth everywhere except at $0$ where the function itself and its derivatives might have steps.

Then,
$$
\begin{align}
f' &= \partial f + (f(0^+)-f(0^-))\,\delta \\
f'' &= \partial^2 f + (f(0^+)-f(0^-))\,\delta' + (\partial f(0^+)-\partial f(0^-))\,\delta \\
f''' &= \partial^3 f + (f(0^+)-f(0^-))\,\delta'' + (\partial f(0^+)-\partial f(0^-))\,\delta' + (\partial^2 f(0^+)-\partial^2 f(0^-)) \delta \\
f'''' &= \partial^4 f + (f(0^+)-f(0^-))\,\delta''' + (\partial f(0^+)-\partial f(0^-))\,\delta'' + (\partial^2 f(0^+)-\partial^2 f(0^-)) \delta' \\ &\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ + (\partial^3 f(0^+)-\partial^3 f(0^-)) \delta \\
\end{align}
$$

Inserting these into the differential equation we find that
$$
\begin{align}
f(0^+)-f(0^-) &= 0 \\
\partial f(0^+)-\partial f(0^-) &= 0 \\
\partial^2 f(0^+)-\partial^2 f(0^-) &= 1 \\
\partial^3 f(0^+)-\partial^3 f(0^-) &= 0 \\
\end{align}
$$